# Using node modules/.js functions in ejs

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, module

I have recently started working with JavaScript and Node and I'm having trouble working with the .ejs files.

I'm trying to implement a button in my page that gets a string inserted in a textarea and runs a function to evaluate if that string is a xml code (more precisely a Vast Tag, but that's not the point.)

So, I have something like this:

```
<div class="clear vastClass">
    <h3> Vast Tag </h3>
<div class="vastClass" hidden>
    <div>
        <p>Please validate your code!</p>
        <input type="button" id ="buttonVast" value="Validate">
    </div>

    <textarea id="vastTag" name="vastTag" class="form_creatives" value="">Insert you Vast Tag</textarea>

</div>
</div>

<script>
    $("#buttonVast").click(function(){
        // TODO
    }
</script>
```

So here are a few questions:

I'm trying to use the node module xml2js to see check the text and I have read something online already (I don't know if they are right). e.g.:

- The browser is running the .ejs file, so if I try to require('xml2js') it won't understand
- I tried to use the browserify package, but I can't seen to make it work
- I can only call a file.js using  if that file is in my public assets folder. (indeed any file I try to access I get an 404 Page Not Found Exception)

So, my questions is if anyone have any tips on a method that works where I can either use the node module inside my script, OR If can define a function in a file.js and then call this function into the script, OR if anyone knows how browserify works and if it can be used to fix my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the reply @mikemjharris, but it doesnt really solve my problem.

After a couple more days searching, I've found out how to use browserify, so I'll answer it myself.

First, I had to create a .js file, let's say, main.js, where I declared and defined all the functions I wanted to use, e.g.

Main.js:

```
var xml2js = require('xml2js')
validateVast = function(vast){
    var parser = xml2js.Parser()
    parser.parseString(vast, function(err, result){
        if(result && !err){
            console.log(result)
        }
        else{
            console.log(err.toString())
        }
    })
}
```

Then, in the terminal I used the command below to add a Bundle file to my public resources folder:

```
browserify folder/main.js -o public/js/xml2jsBundle
```

Then, in my html file, I added the line

```
<script src="js/xml2jsBundle.js"</script>
```

And then was able to call my function in the body of the html like:

```
<body>
    <script src="js/xml2jsBundle.js"</script>
    <input type="button" value="Validate" class="bt_Add" onClick="validate()">
    <textarea id="vastTag" name="vastTag" class="form_creatives" value=""></textarea>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        function validate(){
            var vast = $("#vastTag").val()
            validateVast(vast)
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

Well, I guess this is it.
Thanks for your help, bye

Answer (score 0):

To check if the string in a textarea is xml you can use a regex expression. This checks to see if the input starts with

Here's a working fiddle: http://fiddle.jshell.net/mikemjharris/j1nL8rz0/

The specific code to check for xml:

```
function checkXML () {
  var textToCheck = $('textarea').val();
  if( textToCheck.match(/\<\?xml /) ) {
    alert('this is xml!');
  } else {
    alert('not xml');
  }
}
```